# How to change the value of undefined to blank in sharepoint

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

I have a web page that display a data from sharepoint list in table format. 
This is my code.

```
function getMyListData()
{
var method = "GetListItems";                 
    var webURL =  $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentSite() ;                     
    var list = "ITASList";                      
    var fieldsToRead = "<ViewFields>"+"<FieldRef Name='Name' />" +"</ViewFields>";
    var query = "<Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Subdomain' /><Value Type='Text'>Application Development</Value></Eq></IsNotNull></Where><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='ID'  Ascending='True' /></OrderBy></Query>"; 

$().SPServices
({
      operation: method,
      async: false, 
      webURL: webURL,
      listName: list,
      CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields Properties='True' />",
      CAMLQuery: query,                                                                                     
      completefunc: function (xData, Status)
      {
        $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function()
           {
            var Subdomain = $(this).attr("ows_Subdomain");
            var Product = $(this).attr("ows_Product");
            var Ver =  $(this).attr("ows_Ver");
            var EOS =  $(this).attr("ows_EOS");
            var EOL =  $(this).attr("ows_EOL");
            var SunsetYear =  $(this).attr("ows_SunsetYear");
            var Year18 =  $(this).attr("ows_Year18");

            $("#myHTMLTable").append("<tr align='middle'>" +

            "<td align='left'>"+Subdomain+"</td>" +
            "<td align='left'>"+Product+"</td>" +
            "<td align='left'>"+Ver+"</td>"  +                                         
            "<td align='left'>"+EOS+"</td>" +
            "<td align='left'>"+EOL+"</td>" +
            "<td align='left'>"+SunsetYear+"</td>" +
            "<td align='left'>"+Year18+"</td>" +
            "</tr>");
            });
        }
   });
   };
```

The problem is if there is no data in the list, my web page will display it as undefined. How to change that undefined to blank when it display on the web page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the shorthand ternary operator to do that check.

So, modify your code as below:

```
$(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function()
{
var Subdomain = $(this).attr("ows_Subdomain") ? $(this).attr("ows_Subdomain") : "";
var Product = $(this).attr("ows_Product") ? $(this).attr("ows_Product") : "";
var Ver =  $(this).attr("ows_Ver") ? $(this).attr("ows_Ver") : "";
var EOS =  $(this).attr("ows_EOS") ? $(this).attr("ows_EOS") : "";
var EOL =  $(this).attr("ows_EOL") ? $(this).attr("ows_EOL") : "";
var SunsetYear =  $(this).attr("ows_SunsetYear") ? $(this).attr("ows_SunsetYear") : "";
var Year18 =  $(this).attr("ows_Year18") : $(this).attr("ows_Year18") : "";

// rest of your existing code
```

Basically what this code does is that it checks if the current column has value, if it has it uses that value else assigns empty string to the variable, something like:

```
var Subdomain;
if($(this).attr("ows_Subdomain") != undefined){
    Subdomain = $(this).attr("ows_Subdomain")
}else{
    Subdomain = "" ; // this is empty string
}
```

Comment: I want to ask something with the same code up there... right now i take a query of subdomain with value application development... can i take a value from another page and then use it as my query for the fieldref?

Comment: yes, you can take any value. It depends on how you are extracting that value ? If it  is in another page, then you might need to query that page's property and fetch that value first before making your current query

Comment: yeah i want a value in another page...can you teach me on that...i really need your help...

Comment: i am bit unclear on what exactly you need :( 
could you ask it as a separate new question with more details ? Maybe i can help you if i understand the actual problem. Thanks !

Comment: oh it's ok... i already got how to do it but thank you for the answer and the idea you give it to me...it's help a lot...